# why `head` files are not loaded after ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, echo

To send an echo from a php script, i use ajax. The echo comes in the div with class `echo`. Below is my html structure:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="header-fixed">
       <div class="echo"><!-- in here coming the echos from php --></div>
```

My ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "actions.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),

            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
            $(".echo").html(data);          

            },

       });
```

This is my php script **actions.php**:

```
if($_POST['deletefile']) {
     unlink($_POST['deletefile']);
     echo  '<span class="closebtn">CLOSE</span><br />';
     echo basename($_POST['deletefile']) . ' successful deleted';
     echo '<script>
           $('.closebtn').click(function(){
           $(this).parent('.echomessage').fadeOut(500);
           });
           </script>';  
}
```

The problem: the little js in the echo needs the jquery core file which is in the `head`. But it seems that he is not loaded anymore because when click on the CLOSE button, the echo does not fadeout anymore.

putting the core file also in the echo like below:

```
echo '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
```

works fine. But i guess, this is not how it should be. 
How can i solve this without sending the core file again in the echo? Because it is already in the `head` loaded...

Comment: You can't load js with ajax like that. It won't execute.

Comment: Does it work if you add `header("Content-type: application/javascript");` and remove the `<script>` and `</script>`. That would be the correct way.

Comment: Can you try using `echo '<script>$(document).on("click", ".closebtn", function(){ $(this).parent(".echomessage").fadeOut(500); });</script>';`

Comment: Another thing I've seen a lot of here the last week is the usage of FormData like that. Unless you're uploading files using jQuery's ajax funtion, there's no need for using FormData and setting contentType and processData.

Comment: Also the more correct approach would be to return the status and message as JSON e.g. `header("Content-type: application/json"); echo '[true, "inserted"]';` and place the logic of displaying this JSON inside the success function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element inside which you inject the HTML is `<div class="echo">` where as your jQuery code is searching for something else:

```
$(this).parent('.echomessage')
//              ^---- should be ".echo"
```

Having said that, I would recommend that you revise the server-side script to return a JSON-encoded response and move the logic of displaying it inside the `success` event like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "actions.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: new FormData(this),
    success: function(response) {
        // response could be something like {"success": true, "message": "aaa.txt deleted"}
        $("<span class='closebtn'>CLOSE</span>")
            .appendTo(".echo")
            .after("<br>", response.message)
            .on("click", function() {
                $(this).parent(".echo").fadeOut(500);
            });
        $(".echo").html(data);
    },
});
```

Comment: Well, i agree it **does** work. I forgot to change `$(".echo").html(response);` into `$(".echo").html(data);`

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
 success: function(data) {
          $.getScript( "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" ); //load core file
          $(".echo").html(data);          

        },
```